# Shared element Traisition, Activity's onStop() not called when starting another Activity in android version above 7.0

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I start new activiy with shared element, the old activity's onStop() not called.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SimpleActivityA.this, SimpleActivityB.class);
        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                SimpleActivityA.this,
                imageView,
                ViewCompat.getTransitionName(imageView));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 102, options.toBundle());
```

**This only happen on android version >= 7.0 and has navigation bar**

I want to know why onStop() not called.

Comment: It should be called. Put a Log statement in onStop() method of SimpleActivityA.class and find it in LogCat.

Comment: I am sure onStop() not called, only onPause and onResme is called

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour, onStop not called with SharedElement TransitionAnimation

Comment: Android doesn't call onStop if the Window is translucent in the new activity.